# probablepeople.parse() data to csv file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have script that read data from CSV file and use probablepeople library for results and `probablepeople` have method that is `parse()` I am using it like `probablepeople.parse('some text')` and it is produce output like this
example

```
some text      |  return by probablepeople.parse()
Justin Nappier  | [('Justin', 'GivenName'), ('Nappier', 'Surname')]
Richard Urnberg |  [('Richard', 'CorporationName'), ('Urnberg', 'CorporationName')]
```

so the output is basically this

```
[('text', 'columnname'), ('text', 'columnname'), ('text', 'columnname'), ('text', 'columnname')........]
```

I want to store the data in the CSV file could you please help me with this.

my code is like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import probablepeople
import csv


try:
    # Getting ASINs from the given csv and put into the start_urls
    with open('full_name_submit.csv', 'rbU') as csv_file:
        data = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for url in data:
            print(url[1])
            pr = probablepeople.parse(url[1])
            print(pr)
            # some logic to put data to csv

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: to use probablepeople install library by using  `pip install probablepeople`

Comment: You've used csv.reader already. Why not similarly use [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects)

Comment: Can you post the desired output for the CSV file? Are you meaning to convert a `list` of `tuple`s into a CSV where the second position of the `tuple` determines the CSV column and the first it's value? If so, `CorporationName` is duplicated in your example so you are gonna loose info.

Comment: yes it is okay if I loose the info but I need output

Comment: So the output expected is: `GivenName, Suname, OrganizationName` -
 `Justin, Nappier, ` - `, , Urnberg` being each of the blocks a line on the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in csv stuff but using join() to convert it to a string might help.  Something like this maybe?

```
''.join(str(x) for x in pr)
```

Answer (score 0):

`','.join((x[0] for x in pr))`

Or whatever your separator is.